# Ajax call problem check is user is already registered

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, validation

i'm triying to check if some user is already registered in my database so i'll be able to submit a form.

The problem seems to be that de ajax call is not made, i've tried to check other code's and debug but the problem doesn't looks like i had found.

Any help is good.

Thank you!

HTML Code:

```
 <form method="POST" action="#" onsubmit="return (Inscrito() && Rut());" name=form1>
                      <div class="row">
                      <div class="col">
                        <label class="label">Rut</label>
                        <input type="text" name="rut"  class="input--style-4" id="rut" required  >
                      </div>
                      <div class="col">
                      </div>
                    </div>
 <div class="p-t-15">
 <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--blue" id="submit_inscription" 
type="submit">Inscribirse</button>
                      </div>
 </form>
```

JS Code.

```
function Inscrito(){

 var rut = document.getElementById("rut").value;

 if(rut != ''){

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url : '../controller/validate_inscripcion.php',
     data: {rut : rut},

     success: function(data){
         if(data == 'exists')

             //username exists
             alert('Este rut ya se encuentra registrado!');
             return false;
     },
     error: function(request , status , error){
        alert(request.resposeText);
        return true;

     }
 });
  }else{
alert('Rut incompleto');  
return false; 

}
```

};

PHP Code (controller_inscripcion.php)

```
<?php
  require ('../model/modelo_inscripcion.php');

  $modelo =new modeloInscripcion();
   if(isset($_POST['rut'])){
   var $x = $modelo->validarInscrito($_POST['rut']);


    $db->desconectarBD();

   if($x==true){
    echo 'exists';
   }else{
    echo '';
   }   

exit;
 }
```

PHP Code (model_inscripcion)

```
<?php

  require ('../model/database.php');


   class modeloInscripcion{

public $db;

 function __construct(){

    $this -> db = new DataBase();

}   

public function validarInscrito($rut){

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM person WHERE rut  = "'.$rut.'"';

    $link=  $this -> db->getConexion();
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    return false;
    }
    return true;

}

}
```

Comment: Thank's i'm still learning, but being honest that's not the problem.

Comment: Where is submit button..?

Comment: I thougth that the submit button is obvious, i'll edit the post so the button apears.